# Value of type 'List (of Strings) cannot be converted to String()

Tags: vb.net

Whenever I use this code in a private solution it works perfectly, but whenever I try to implement it on my main program I get the above error. Any idea on what could block the proper usage of this over the two solutions?

```
Private Sub GameID_Validating(sender As Object, e As CancelEventArgs) Handles GameID.Validating
           LoadAlreadyUsed(dataFile)
    If ActiveControl.Equals(sender) Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim tb = DirectCast(sender, TextBox)
    Dim txt = GameID.Text
    If Not txt = "" Then
        Dim res As String = Replace(txt, Space(1), Space(0))
        txt = res
        GameID.Text = res
        If alreadyUsed.Contains(txt, StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) Then
            'MessageBox.Show("This code has already been used.", "Cheat attempt violation", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
            GameID.BackColor = Color.Red
            GameID.Select()
        Else
            GameID.BackColor = Color.LimeGreen
            alreadyUsed.Add(txt)
    → → → →   File.WriteAllLines(dataFile, alreadyUsed)
        End If
    End If
    If alreadyUsed.Count > 30 Then
        Do Until alreadyUsed.Count = 30
            alreadyUsed.RemoveAt(2)
        Loop
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Shall we assume the line with the arrows is what throws the exception?  What are `dataFile` and `alreadyUsed`?  Where do you define those?

Comment: That is correct,sorry for the poor formating , the arrows point towards the line with the error. alreadyUsed is a list of strings and datafile is a string  with the path to the txt file.Both are defined at the start of form1

Comment: Strings is a module in the vb namespace. It is not a datatype class or structure. String is what you need. `Dim lst As New List(Of String)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `datafile` is the full path to the file you want to write to and `alreadyused` is the list of string...

[File.WriteAllLines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writealllines?view=netcore-3.1) does NOT accept list of string as a second parameter. This method accepts an array of strings. So, you can use `ToArray()` method to convert list of strings into an array of strings.

```
File.WriteAllLines(dataFile, alreadyUsed.ToArray())
```

See: [List(of T).ToArray()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.toarray?view=netcore-3.1)

Comment: Thank you it worked. For educational purposes do you have any idea why on another solution the exact same line "File.WriteAllLines" worked?

Comment: The only reason is that the second parameter is an array and does not need conversion. ;)

Comment: One of the overloads of  `WriteAllLines`, `WriteAllLines(String, IEnumerable<String>) ` accepts a `IEnumerable<string>`, so you can pass any collections that derives from it. `List<string>` included, of course. The *problem* here is that the OP is using an old Framework: FW 3.5, possibly, since this overload is available from, IIRC, .Net 4.0.